# Turn off mesh layer in ArcGIS Pro 3D Scene

Tags: arcgis-pro, grids-graticules

I was working with a profile view of an elevation surface in a local scene, and I accidentally pressed something that made a mesh appear at a constant elevation in the scene.  It looks like a grid when zoomed in but is partially transparent.  I don't know how it got turned on, and I don't know how to get rid of it. It is not a layer in the TOC.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out what it was... There's a small grid icon at the bottom of the scene view, next to the reference scale (see pic).  It was turned on... Clicking it again turns it off.

[image]